# Runtime Error with _mm_set1_epi32

Tags: c++11, simd

I am trying to use SIMD instructions in some projects and everything is working fine, except that I can't use the _mm_set1_epi32(x) command (I can still just use _mm_set_epi32(x,x,x,x) and it works fine) but as soon as I want to use code from another source where the command is used I get a "memory access error" message (please excuse that I don't have the correct english translation for the error, I tried translating it from German where it is Speicherzugriffsfehler)

Some additional information:

- I get the error in an empty project where I do nothing except use the command
- I got this problem with no other command

For code examples, there is not really something to post here, except this:

```
int main() {
    __m128i test = _mm_set1_epi32(1);
}
```

The error is at runtime, no problems with compiling.

Comment: [mcve], which version of which compiler with what options, etc.

Comment: I use the following in my makefile:
CXX=clang++
CXXFLAGS=-Wall -v -g -std=c++11 -Wall   -pedantic -msse -mmmx -msse2 -msse4.1 -v -mavx2

Comment: Still no [mcve] ?

Comment: Put some codes here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. The flags I used to compile where wrong, thats also the reason why I didn't put any code, it would be just 1 line where I try to execute the command and the include for it in a main function.

So to the solution, I use now:

```
-g -std=c++11 -Wall   -pedantic -msse4.1 -v
```

and before I used:

```
-g -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -msse -mmmx -msse2 -msse4.1 -v -mavx2
```